# How to connect laptop to internet via Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, internet, wifi-tethering

I am traveling with my notebook and I want to connect to the internet using my cellphone data connection.  I have a Galaxy S2, and I've set up a portable Wi-Fi hotspot, which my laptop successfully connects to.  But thereafter I cannot connect to the internet.  Can't browse, ping, nothing.  All I can ping is the gateway (which I presume is my droid).

Is there some secret switch I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure your carrier isn't restricting tethering?

Comment: @onik - could be, but it's no longer relevant - I managed to get it working with a USB cable and that sufficed for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I wasn't being patient enough.  It took a little while for my phone to realize it needed to connect to data services; after that the tethering worked fine.  It helped for me to open my email on my phone, just to give it a little nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your carrier, [FoxFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi) may help you out. It allows you to share you mobile data plan as a WiFi hot spot. Just be careful not to use too much or your carrier will get suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your service provider has to activate the ability to use your cellphone as a hotspot.  For Sprint, there is a monthly fee associated with that feature.